# Java Exceptions on weka k fold programme

Tags: java, weka, cross-validation

I would like to perform a 10 fold cross validation on my data and I used the weka java programme. However, I encountered exception problems.

Here is the exceptions:

```
    ---Registering Weka Editors---
    Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable converter found for ''!

    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.<init>(ConverterUtils.java:137)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.read(ConverterUtils.java:441)
    at crossvalidationmultipleruns.CrossValidationMultipleRuns.main(CrossValidationMultipleRuns.java:45)

C:\Users\TomXavier\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Here is the programme I used:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.core.Utils;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Performs a single run of cross-validation.
 *
 * Command-line parameters:
 * <ul>
 *    <li>-t filename - the dataset to use</li>
 *    <li>-x int - the number of folds to use</li>
 *    <li>-s int - the seed for the random number generator</li>
 *    <li>-c int - the class index, "first" and "last" are accepted as well;
 *    "last" is used by default</li>
 *    <li>-W classifier - classname and options, enclosed by double quotes; 
 *    the classifier to cross-validate</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * Example command-line:
 * <pre>
 * java CrossValidationSingleRun -t anneal.arff -c last -x 10 -s 1 -W "weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25"
 * </pre>
 *
 * @author FracPete (fracpete at waikato dot ac dot nz)
 */
public class CrossValidationSingleRun {

  /**
   * Performs the cross-validation. See Javadoc of class for information
   * on command-line parameters.
   *
   * @param args        the command-line parameters
   * @throws Excecption if something goes wrong
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // loads data and set class index
    Instances data = DataSource.read(Utils.getOption("C:/Users/TomXavier/Documents/MATLAB/total_data.arff", args));
    String clsIndex = Utils.getOption("first", args);
    if (clsIndex.length() == 0)
      clsIndex = "last";
    if (clsIndex.equals("first"))
      data.setClassIndex(0);
    else if (clsIndex.equals("last"))
      data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
    else
      data.setClassIndex(Integer.parseInt(clsIndex) - 1);

    // classifier
    String[] tmpOptions;
    String classname;
    tmpOptions     = Utils.splitOptions(Utils.getOption("weka.classifiers.trees.J48", args));
    classname      = tmpOptions[0];
    tmpOptions[0]  = "";
    Classifier cls = (Classifier) Utils.forName(Classifier.class, classname, tmpOptions);

    // other options
    int seed  = Integer.parseInt(Utils.getOption("1", args));
    int folds = Integer.parseInt(Utils.getOption("10", args));

    // randomize data
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    Instances randData = new Instances(data);
    randData.randomize(rand);
    if (randData.classAttribute().isNominal())
      randData.stratify(folds);

    // perform cross-validation
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(randData);
    for (int n = 0; n < folds; n++) {
      Instances train = randData.trainCV(folds, n);
      Instances test = randData.testCV(folds, n);
      // the above code is used by the StratifiedRemoveFolds filter, the
      // code below by the Explorer/Experimenter:
      // Instances train = randData.trainCV(folds, n, rand);

      // build and evaluate classifier
      Classifier clsCopy = Classifier.makeCopy(cls);
      clsCopy.buildClassifier(train);
      eval.evaluateModel(clsCopy, test);
    }

    // output evaluation
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("=== Setup ===");
    System.out.println("Classifier: " + cls.getClass().getName() + " " + Utils.joinOptions(cls.getOptions()));
    System.out.println("Dataset: " + data.relationName());
    System.out.println("Folds: " + folds);
    System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("=== " + folds + "-fold Cross-validation ===", false));
  }
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Adding the driver to classpath?

Comment: According to weka's website, the driver error can be ignored since I am not trying to access a database. But if the problem is related to the databse, I can try to fix it. Any other possible solution for this problem?
Thanks for the reply!